# Remove Indentation for a Single Paragraph

Tags: indentation

Is there a way to remove the indentation at the beginning of a paragraph *for a single paragraph*.  I know I could do

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
This is my paragraph.  Blah blah blah.
\setlength{\parindent}{default}
```

Where `default` is whatever the default indentation is for the document class I am using (part of the problem is that I don't know what this default value is).  I feel as if there should be a better way to accomplish this than by the above method.  I am looking for a solution of the form:

```
\noindent
This is my paragraph.  Blah blah blah.
```

Is there a way to do this, or will I have to resort to the former method?  If I have to resort to the former method, what is the default indentation value for the `amsart` document class?

Comment: Are you saying that `\noindent` does not work for you? If so, can you provide a a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass`.

Comment: You can see the default indentation by using `\the\parindent`, normally defined as 1.5em for full width text and 1em for two column.

Comment: It feels like you did not actually try your sample code with `\noindent`, since it works.

Comment: @RyanReich You are correct, I did not even try `\noindent`.  I just used the '`\noindent`' example to illustrated the kind of solution I was looking for.  I did not realize it would actually work!

Comment: This is an excellent example of why you should experiment before posting a question.

Comment: @Seamus: and/or an excellent example of how when you think a command name you would like to use with TeX is actually exactly the same-named that is already existing! :D

Answer (score 284, accepted):

As the example below illustrates, `\noindent` suppresses paragraph indentation when used at the beginning of a paragraph.  If used in the middle of a paragraph, it is ignored and does not suppress the paragraph indentation.

Also, you can always group things within a `{}` so that any settings within their are not in effect after the group.  This saves you from having to store the old setting and restore it afterwards.

[image]

### Notes:

- One can use `\indent` to produce a horizontal space equal to the width of the paragraph indentation.
- The `[showframe]` option was used with the `geometry` package to show the margins so that the indentation is clearly shown.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
This is my paragraph 1 and is indented.  Blah blah blah.

\noindent
This is my paragraph 2 but is not indented since it was started with noindent.  Blah blah blah.

This is my paragraph 3 and is indented.  Blah blah blah.

{\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
This is my paragraph 4 but is not indented since parindent was set to 0 within this group.  Blah blah blah.
}

This is my paragraph 5 and is indented since the above setlength was within a group.  Blah blah blah.
\end{document}
```