# How to make a new line without indenting?

Tags: spacing, indentation

How can I make a new line without it being indented?  Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, reqno]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{bardmacros}

\begin{document}

\demo

However, since $y \notin B$, we have $\mathbb{X\restriction_B} = 0$.  This is a contradiction, because $1 \neq 0$.  Therefore, $A=B$ must be true for $\mathbb{X\restriction_A} = \mathbb{X\restriction_B}$.\\\

$\Rightarrow$  Let $\mathbb{X\restriction_A} \neq \mathbb{X\restriction_B}$ and let $A=B$.
\edemo
\end{document}
```

And this is what the output looks like.  The indent right before the => is what I'd like to eliminate:

[image: And the output]

I am very new the LaTeX, so thanks for your patience!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) We are patient, but I have a small request :) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can try adding `\noindent` before the line that you did not want indented. See [Remove Paragraph Indentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38829/remove-paragraph-indentation/).

Comment: Or don't use an blank line, and write at the end of the preceding line: `\bigskip\\\`.

Comment: Thanks Bernard and @Peter Grill!  Those both worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `\\`. This will initiate a new line without starting a new paragraph. If you are inside an environment you can also use `\newline`.
To start a new paragraph you would use `\par`. `\noindent` should only be used when the paragraph does not directly follow another paragraph but something else such as a table or a section head (most styles do this automatically).

Comment: I think I tried \\ initially, and it was giving me the indent.  But thank you, I won't use \noindent then.  (How did you make your code highlighted grey, btw?)

Comment: @Maclafel7 By using the ` character. (The {} button on the editor)

Comment: Can you explain what's bad about using `\noindent` when a paragraph follows another paragraph?

Comment: You are then working against your documentclass. If you don't want indenting of paragraphs you can configure it such that you have vertical space instead (or neither). In regular texts there should be little reasons for exceptions.