# What is causing the white on the left of this page filling picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I am trying to make a page filling picture with a relative coordinate system. I used `geometry` to set the margings to 0pt and am drawing the picture using `tikz`. It almoast worked, but I can still see white at the left of the page and I can't explain why.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a3paper,margin=0pt]{geometry}%No margins, A3 paper
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,backgrounds,positioning,shadings}
\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.01\paperwidth,y=0.01\paperheight, very thick]%Coordinates relative to paper size
    \fill[color = green!70] (0,0) rectangle (20,100);%(0,0) should be at the very left of the page, but it is't.
        \fill[left color = green!70,right color =blue!50] (20,0) rectangle (26,100);
        \fill[color = blue!50] (26,0) rectangle (72,100);
        \fill[left color =blue!50, right color = red!60] (72,0) rectangle (78,100);
        \fill[color = red!60] (78,0) rectangle (100,100);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: The output]

I did not expect to see that white bar at the left of the page, since I thought I had specified the coordinates in such a way that `(0,0)` is at the very left of the page. What went wrong?

Comment: Add `\noindent` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @percusse It worked.  Thank you. Would you like to turn you comment into an anwser so I can accept?

Comment: Good to hear. I think we can close it as a duplicate of [Q38829](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38829/3235). Would you agree?

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call it a duplicate. I actually got half a mind to delete this question. It's just a silly thing I overlooked and it is unlikely that anyone will run into the same issue.