# Misalignment in math mode

Tags: math-mode, alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\(f: I \to \mathbb{R}
\\
x_1, x_2 \in I\)
\end{document}
```

When I type this in LaTeX, the two rows don't align corectly, they start at different points. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the alignment in math mode searched?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\(\begin{array}{ll}
f\colon I \to \mathbb{R} &\\
x_1, x_2 \in I
\end{array}\)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The misalignment is caused by the usual paragraph indentation. `\(` starts an inline math, similar to normal text starting a pagraph.
With standard settings a paragraph is indented, i.e., the first line is indented by initial horizontal space (of width `\parindent`), whereas the following lines are unindented.
See [Remove Indentation for a Single Paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38829/remove-indentation-for-a-single-paragraph) how to suppress the indentation for some paragraphs or use a package like "parskip" to change from indentation to vertical skip between two paragraphs.

Use display math, e.g., `\[` or one of the math environments, e.g., `equation` or `align`, if you want to get your formulas in separate lines and aligned.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f: I \to \mathbb{R}
\\
x_1, x_2 \in I
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Avoid using `\\` to start a new line in a normal paragraph. Use `\\` only within environments in which it is defined with the meaning to start a new line entry. Within a normal text paragraph you will get an "underfull hbox" warning message.  A new paragraph is started at a new line ìf you input an empty line or a `\par` in your document file, usually with the first line indented.)