# Strange Indentation after inserting images

Tags: indentation, includegraphics, figure-placement

I'm working on my thesis (I have no previous knowledge about Latex), I noticed that after inserting images, something weird is going on with the indentation. I don't know how to upload the Latex code, so here there is a screenshot of the script:

[image]

And the appearence of the page is the following:

[image]

As you can see there is a gap between the beginning of the second text, but I didn't insert it. And this error is repeated:

[image]

So I don't understand what is messing with the text, is it something with the image? And there is more in line 27, if I remove the \newline and insert \ the indentation is correct, but why? Is the same thing, isn't it? I have already tried to use \centering before the text, but this gives the page a bad look

Comment: Screenshots of some code snippets are not enough to reproduce a problem. So you should always show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. So currently I can only guess, that the intend it the normal `\parindent`. BTW: You should not use `\newline` to make paragraph skips. Use, e.g., [package `parskip`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) instead, if you always want paragraph distance instead of indent, if the class does not provide it.

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664/277964 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38829/277964

Comment: Welcome! It seems that you are confusing newlines and paragraphs. Please take a look at https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Paragraphs_and_new_lines and maybe at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the usual paragraph indent. It makes sense for books. If you have good reasons against it, you could set in the document preamble `\parindent0mm`.

And do not use `\newline` for a linebreak. Just use either an empty line, `\smallskip`, `\medskip`, or `\bigskip`.

Comment: May I ask you what's the difference between the \newline and the empty lines you have suggested? Just to understand better

Comment: This is explained here quite well: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines